# Reconocimiento facial reconocer varias caras al mismo tiempo

Tags: python

Estimados buenas noches estoy trabajando con reconocimiento facial y me encontré con un escollo, porque no me doy cuenta como hacer para recorrer la carpeta en este caso es la carpeta Imágenes donde tengo fotos con las caras de cada persona, ahora bien preciso cargar en un array con los nombre que figuran en la carpeta imágenes. inserto el codigo de loque estoy haciendo para que sea mas claro

Comment: No has insertado nada de código.

Comment: ¿Entonces tu problema es listar los archivos de un directorio? Revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
 

dir_faces = 'Imagenes/'
contenido = os.listdir(dir_faces) 
#Cargar la imagen de ejemplo con nuestro rostro:
imagen_personal = face_recognition.load_image_file(contenido)


#Extraer los 'encodings' que caracterizan nuestro rostro:
personal_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(imagen_personal)[0]
 
#Definir un array con los encodings y nuestro nombre:
encodings_conocidos = [
    personal_encodings
]
nombres_conocidos = [#"aca deberia mostrar el nombre dela persona a través de una variable"
]
For fichero in contenido:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_faces, fichero)) and fichero.endswith('.jpg'):
        nombres_conocidos.append(fichero)
```